# Python Pandas updating same named columns and also done other calculation while in loop

Tags: python, pandas

In dataframe, I want to iterate over same named columns and while iterating, when their sum exceeds "val_n" value. I want 4 things:
1) exceed_when (at what iteration it exceed from "val_n" value)
2) sum_col (sum of same named columns)
3) At the point of exceed when, I want to replace corresponding col value as (col - (sum_col - val_n)
4) And after exceed_when point, I want to replace rest of cols value to 0.

Dataframe look like:

```
id  col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8    col9    col10   col11   col12   col13   col14   val_n
1   350 350 350 350 350 350 350 350 350 350 0   0   0   0   3105.61
2   50  50  55  105 50  0   50  100 50  50  50  50  1025    1066.86 3185.6
3   0   0   0   0   0   3495.1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3495.1  3477.76
```

Required Dataframe:

```
id  col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8    col9    col10   col11   col12   col13   col14   val_n   exceed_when sum_col
1   350 350 350 350 350 350 350 350 305.61  0   0   0   0   0   3105.61 9   3500
2   50  50  55  105 50  0   50  100 50  50  50  50  1025    1066.86 3185.6      2751.86
3   0   0   0   0   0   3477.76 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3477.76 6   6990.2
```

This is what I have tried:

```
def trans(row):
    row['sum_col'] = 0
    row['exceed_ind'] = 0

    for i in range(1, 15):
        row['sum_col'] += row['col' + str(i)]

        if ((row['exceed_ind'] == 0) &
            (row['sum_col'] >= row['val_n'])):

            row['exceed_ind'] = 1
            row['exceed_when'] = i

        else:
            continue

        if row['exceed_when'] == i:
            row['col' + str(i)] = (
                row['col' + str(i)] - (
                    row['sum_col'] - row['val_n']))

        elif row['exceed_when'] < i:
            row['col' + str(i)] = 0

        else:
            row['col' + str(i)] = row['col' + str(i)]
    return row

df1 = df.apply(trans, axis=1)
```

I am getting right results for sum_col, exceed when but conditions elif row['exceed_when'] < i , doesn't seems to be working and its not updated the expected 4th point i.e. replace rest of cols value to 0. I am NOT sure what I miss.

DDL to generate DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                   'col1': [350, 50, 0],
                   'col2': [350, 50, 0],
                   'col3': [350, 55, 0],
                   'col4': [350, 105, 0],
                   'col5' : [350, 50, 0],
                   'col6': [350, 0, 3495.1],
                   'col7': [350, 50, 0],
                   'col8': [350, 100, 0],
                   'col9': [350, 50, 0],
                   'col10': [350, 50, 0],
                   'col11': [0, 50, 0],
                   'col12': [0, 50, 0],
                   'col13': [0, 1025, 0],
                   'col14': [0, 1066.86, 3495.1],
                   'val_n': [3105.61, 3185.6, 3477.76]
                   })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the `.apply` function will only pass a copy of the `row` and all updates happen on the copy only, not the original `DataFrame` itself. In this case, you have to loop through the rows and update them using the index.

```
df['sum_col'] = 0
df['exceed_ind'] = 0
df['exceed_when'] = 0

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    sum_col = 0
    exceed_ind = 0
    exceed_when = 0

    for i in range(1, 15):
        sum_col += row['col' + str(i)]

        if ((exceed_ind == 0) &
            (sum_col >= row['val_n'])):

            exceed_ind = 1
            exceed_when = i
            df.loc[idx, 'exceed_ind'] = exceed_ind
            df.loc[idx, 'exceed_when'] = exceed_when
            df.loc[idx, 'col' + str(i)] = (row['col' + str(i)] - (sum_col - row['val_n']))

        elif (exceed_ind==1) & (exceed_when < i):
            df.loc[idx, 'col' + str(i)] = 0

        df.loc[idx, 'sum_col'] = sum_col

print(df)
```

Result:

```
    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5     col6  col7  col8    col9  col10  col11  \
id                                                                            
1    350   350   350   350   350   350.00   350   350  305.61      0      0   
2     50    50    55   105    50     0.00    50   100   50.00     50     50   
3      0     0     0     0     0  3477.76     0     0    0.00      0      0   

    col12  col13    col14    val_n  sum_col  exceed_ind  exceed_when  
id                                                                    
1       0      0     0.00  3105.61  3500.00           1            9  
2      50   1025  1066.86  3185.60  2751.86           0            0  
3       0      0     0.00  3477.76  6990.20           1            6
```

Comment: Thanks davidbilla! Thanks for your answer, its correct. But your answer reminds me what I missed in my code i.e. initialize df['exceed_when'] = 0 and also one less if condition.

Comment: @Anku Glad that I was able to help! Cheers :)